# What is the idiomatic "functional" way to take an Optional<String> and return a default string if null or empty, a modified string otherwise?

Tags: java, functional-programming, coding-style, option-type

What is the idiomatic, minimal (perhaps functional?) way to take an `Optional<String>` and say,

- return a default string, *e.g.* `true` if null or empty, or
- return a modified string, *e.g.* `query_str = <str>` otherwise.

Of course, there's my clunky attempt:

```
Optional<String> queryMaybe; // Given.
String clause = "true";
if (queryMaybe.isPresent() && !queryMaybe.get().isEmpty()) {
  clause = "query_str = " + queryMaybe.get();
}
```

But the surrounding code written by my colleagues seems to use a lot of, what I think might be called, "functional" style—chaining. For example,

```
String externalTraffickedStateClauses = StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(
    externalTraffickedStateQueries.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" OR ")), "false");
```

and

```
SORTORDERBY orderBy = orderByMaybe.orElse(DEFAULT_ORDER_BY);
```

So, I'm trying to conform to their style as much as I can, *i.e.* chain `stream`, `filter`, `orElse`, etc. Not sure if it's because I'm coming from a C++ background or because my learnings are simply outdated, but this is still very unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
return queryMaybe
    .filter(query -> !query.isEmpty())
    .map(query -> "query_str = " + query)
    .orElse("true")
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like the style! Is there a name for this? (_e.g._ functional)

Comment: Lambda Expressions on JDK8 +

Comment: Use String#isEmpty instead of comparing it to an empty string.